# Loading server statuses after the webpage

Tags: php

Okay, so this is my problem; i've currently got a (kinda) working webpage that uses a minecraft query to check a minecraft server and the Teamspeak framework for PHP to check my teamspeak server.

The problem now is that it takes a very long time to check these things and the website pauses loading until it gets if the servers are online or offline.

Is there any way to load the website first and then check if the servers are up?
And also is there any way to reload this once in a while without reloading the rest of the page.

I would imagine you could do this with JavaScript, but since i've never used it, i don't know.

NOTE:
The reason i'm not posting the code is cause there's some sensetive information in it, and i don't know if it's needed. If it is, tell me.

Comment: You need to learn Javascript and use AJAX or web sockets.

Comment: Use a javascript ajax call to load the script that checks if the server is up into a div. You can also use javascript to refresh the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an AJAX call to a PHP script (which is on your server) which then queries and checks the status of the servers and sends back the result to the client. This will cause the script to be called every time the page  is loaded and may cause heavy resource usage.

Alternatively, you could periodically check (using a [cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), or similar) the status of your servers and store them in a database and display them when requested.

Answer (score 1):

It's common to use javascript for this kind of pattern. Normally you would have the javascript make a request to another page on your server to get back just that data (generally in json form). Look into ajax to see how it's done but best to use a js library to do the work for you - jquery is very common. Depending on what you need to do you may find a framework useful - AngularJS is my poison of choice.

Answer (score 1):

I’d go with JavaScript and XHR or WebSockets as well. But just in case that’s too big a big step for you, you could also try serving your results in chunks (with the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` HTTP header).

You could then output your list of servers one-by-one and each chunk of data would be displayed by the browser as it becomes available. For this to work, you need to first disable any kind of output buffering (`while(ob_get_level() > 0) ob_end_clean();`), set the header explicitly using PHP’s `header` function, and use `flush()` after each chunk. Ideally, your HTML should be arranged in a way so that all other information (besides the server status) is output before that.

Also, please note that not all browsers will have the same interval when updating the DOM with new chunks and you’re relying entirely on the browser’s tag soup parsing as long as the HTML document is “unfinished”. That being said, this is a convenient way of avoiding scripting to achieve your goal.

Alternatively, you could also try embedding the status section into your static page with an `<iframe>` or `<object>` tag.